# random number generator without repetaion

Tags: vb.net, random

I am new to programming. I am making an application in `VB.net`. I want that on loading of a particular form, a random number will be generated as `1 or 2 or 3`. When the form would be loaded 2nd time, a random number would be generated from `1, 2 or 3` but different than it is generated as earlier. And when form would be loaded 3rd time, a random number would be generated from `1, 2 or 3` but different than the previous 2 times, i.e. no repetition of the random numbers.

For example if on first time form load, random number is 3, then second time it should be either 1 or 2. And if second time form load RN is 2, then third time form load it should be 1.

I will be thankful if someone could help me in writing this code in vb.net.

Comment: Create a static random generator and use that instance for all the forms. It's usually adviced to only have one random generator per thread OR application depending on design.

Comment: Just make a standard random number generator, store the generated number somewhere, then when the generator runs again, add a statement to check if the number generated is equal to any of the numbers that you've stored.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the next random from the list and then remove it so it can't be picked again.

```
Dim rndList As New List(Of Integer) From {1,2,3}
Static rnd As New Random
Do Until rndlist.Count = 0
  'get the index by random
  Dim nextValue As Integer = rnd.Next(0, rndList.Count))
  'this is the value at the index
  Debug.Write(rndList(nextValue))
  'remove this item 
  rndList.RemoveAt(nextValue)
Loop
```